# ASP.NET StateBag and Custom Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, custom-server-controls

Lets pretend that for some reason I want to create a custom control that is derived from Control and not WebControl.  Let us also assume that I need to process attributes (i.e. implement IAttributeAccessor) and that I want to do so by using an AttributeCollection just like WebControl does.

WebControl implements the Attributes property like this:

```
public AttributeCollection Attributes
{
    get
    {
        if (this.attrColl == null)
        {
            if (this.attrState == null)
            {
                this.attrState = new StateBag(true);
                if (base.IsTrackingViewState])
                {
                    this.attrState.TrackViewState();
                }
            }
            this.attrColl = new AttributeCollection(this.attrState);
        }
        return this.attrColl;
    }
}
```

Note the following:

1. You cannot create an AttributeCollection without giving it a StateBag.
2. We have to create a new StateBag.  It is not wise to reuse the controls StateBag because an attribute may have the name as a value stored by the control.
3. We cannot call TrackViewState on the StateBag because this is an internal method.
4. StateBag is a sealed class.

So as I understand it if I want to use an AttributeCollection I have to use a new StateBag which can never (without resorting to tricks like reflection) actually manage state correctly.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call TrackViewState on a custom StateBag, you have to cast it to its interface.

```
StateBag mybag = new StateBag();
(mybag as IStateManager).TrackViewState();
```

I'm guessing this design decision was made to hide the implementation of ViewState from consumers.  There is some information about implementing custom state tracking on the [documentation page for IStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.istatemanager.aspx).

Comment: It is a call to the StateBag's TrackViewState which is internal.

Comment: Its sad but I was actually more confused by the hiding of the interface I didn't catch the explicit implementation of the interface although I should have inferred it from the fact that they were able to make it internal. Thanks for setting me straight.